# PDO prepared statement with insertion in database

Tags: mysql, prepared-statement

Please i have this quetion,
I have here:

```
$query = $db->prepare('Update survey_content  set '.$type.' = '.$type.'+1  where id = '.$where);
$query->execute();
```

I'm new to PDO and i really don't know how to create a new query, i need to add a record on the database, is it ok like this?

```
$query1 = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO daily (selected)
VALUES (.$type.)');
$query1->execute();
```

Comment: is your column name variable? That won't work.

Comment: The first query works, i just need to make one similiar to it, my column name selected is a varchar type...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a placeholder and fill the value in the `execute` method

```
$query1 = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO daily (selected)
                        VALUES (?)");
$query1->execute($selected_data);
```

or bind the parameter seperately

```
$query1 = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO daily (selected)
                        VALUES (:sel_dat)");
$query1->bindParam(":sel_dat",$selected_data);
$query1->execute();
```

Comment: A few word of background as a complement to this answer: the purpose of using a prepared statements is to write "template" queries having "placeholders" for the actual values. This will have the double benefit of (1) allowing to *reuse* the same query for different set of values (2) to let the DB adapter (the "driver") escape all "special characters" that could be in the values with the notable advantage to prevent SQL injection.